# The system clock of stm32 blue pill is very unstable

Tags: stm32

I'm using an stm32 blue pill. The clock seems to be unstable. Could this be because of the cheap parts on the board? Or else, is there something that I'm missing here.  Also, did anyone else face the same? Thanks in advance for answering

Comment: How do you measure it? Could you add an oscilloscope or logic analyzer screenshot?

Comment: Very unstable doesn't mean much. The datasheet of the STM32 will give you the  "unstability" you can expect on the internal oscillator. if you need more precision you have to feed the STM32 with an external clock.

Comment: I've been using the external crystal as the base for the pll and multiple it to 72mhz. Comming to how I measured. I programmed a date time clock and observed that I was getting Extra 10 seconds or so for every minute. I agree it a very crude way to measure things but at least I thought the clock would accurate for seconds.